# Initializing plugin factory statically

Tags: c++

I have plugin based architecture, where I have factory class:

```
class PluginFactory {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<Plugin> GetPlugin(PluginType type);

 private:
  static std::map<PluginType, std::shared_ptr<Plugin>> plugin_map_;
};
```

I want to implement `Register(type)` where it will add instance to `map`. From each plugin_file, I want to call macro `REGISTER_PLUGIN()` which will call `Register()`. How do I do this in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the "Auto-Registering Factory" pattern.

You can find an article here: [C++ Tutorial: Auto Registering Factory](http://derydoca.com/2019/03/c-tutorial-auto-registering-factory/)

As always, use with care. Just registering your types manually in a central place might be good enough and save you a lot of headache.